# JS: Loop forces ascending sorting, how to keep defined order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two loops, one big for all tables and inner, smaller with selected tables (to be groupped later on):

```
        var tables = data.tables;
        ar_1 = [29, 21, 19, 27, 28];

        for (var i = 12; i < tables.length; i++) {
            for( var j = 0; j < ar_1.length; j++) {
                if(ar_1[j] == tables[i][0]) {
                    div.append(
                        '<img src="xxx"><span>' + tables[i][1] + '</span>'
                    );
                }
            }
```

Both loops work perfeclty well, the problem I have is that I want to keep order as listed inside the inner array and the output always forces ascending sorting, so the result is 19, 21, 27, 28, 29.

What can I do to keep the order of the result as specified inside the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through `ar_1` in the outer loop instead:

```
for (var j = 0; j < ar_1.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 12; i < tables.length; i++) {
    if (ar_1[j] == tables[i][0]) {
      div.append(
        '<img src="xxx"><span>' + tables[i][1] + '</span>'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You also might consider using array methods instead, which are more functional and arguably easier to read. If each item in `ar_1` has one matching element in the `tables` array, then:

```
ar_1.forEach((findNum) => {
  const foundTable = tables.find(([num]) => num === findNum);
  div.append(
    '<img src="xxx"><span>' + foundTable[1] + '</span>'
  )
});
```

Comment: The first option worked for me - I need to repeat code with different AR number to have `ar_2.`, `ar_3` and so on (so far I have three sections). The second idea displayed spans in correct order but multiplied the output by as many times as there are tables, so I couldn't use it. Thank you for your input!